# python re.sub : replace substring with string

Tags: python, regex

In python,

with `re.sub`, how I can replace a substring with a new string ?

from

```
number = "20"
s = "hello number 10, Agosto 19"
```

to

```
s = "hello number 20, Agosto 19"
```

I try

```
re.sub(r'number ([0-9]*)', number, s)
```

#### EDIT

the number `10` is a example, the number in the string can be any number.

Comment: have you tried anything? Where you got stuck?

Comment: Yes, you can do that using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub).

Comment: `"hello number 10, Agosto 19".replace("10","20")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean this?

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.sub(r'10', r'20', "hello number 10, Agosto 19")
>>> m
'hello number 20, Agosto 19'
```

OR

Using lookbehind,

```
>>> number = "20"
>>> number
'20'
>>> m = re.sub(r'(?<=number )\d+', number, "hello number 10, Agosto 19")
>>> m
'hello number 20, Agosto 19'
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not use regex for such simple cases. Normal [string manipulation](http://devdocs.io/python/library/stdtypes#str.replace) is enough (and fast):

```
s = "hello number 10, Agosto 19"
s = s.replace('10', '20')
```

Comment: Unless of course `'1010'` shouldn't be converted to `'2020'` and the OP is omitting the fact they're really after how to replace *words* (eg, use of regex word boundaries)

Comment: I know it is more than 3 years after your answer. I have a question: what if there were multiple instances of the target string, and I need only to replace a specific one? for instance, `s = "hello number 10, Agosto 19 if you like 10"`, I want to just substitute the second 10?

Comment: @Heinz nothing out-of-the-box. You can implement something along this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35091557/1190388

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the number but know it is followed by a `,`

```
import re
re.sub("\d+(?=,)","20",s) # one or more digits followed by a ,
hello number 20, Agosto 19

import re
re.sub("(\d+)","20",s,1) # first occurrence
hello number 20, Agosto 19
```

Comment: Your lookahead is incorrect. It should be `\d+(?=,)`