# Replace specific instance in string - Python

Tags: python, string, replace

I know that the following is how to replace a string with another string i

`line.replace(x, y)`

But I only want to replace the second instance of x in the line. How do you do that?
Thanks

EDIT
I thought I would be able to ask this question without going into specifics but unfortunately none of the answers worked in my situation. I'm writing into a text file and I'm using the following piece of code to change the file.

```
with fileinput.FileInput("Player Stats.txt", inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace(chosenTeam, teamName), end='')
```

But if chosenTeam occurs multiple times then all of them are replaced.
How can I replace only the nth instance in this situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: He meant python though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace nth occurrence of substring in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091557/replace-nth-occurrence-of-substring-in-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bonus, this is a method to replace "NTH" occurrence in a string

```
def nth_replace(str,search,repl,index):
    split = str.split(search,index+1)
    if len(split)<=index+1:
        return str
    return search.join(split[:-1])+repl+split[-1]
```

**example:**

```
nth_replace("Played a piano a a house", "a", "in", 1) # gives "Played a piano in a house"
```

Answer (score 4):

That's actually a little tricky.  First use `str.find` to get an index *beyond* the first occurrence.  Then slice and apply the replace (with count 1, so as to replace only one occurrence).

```
>>> x = 'na'
>>> y = 'banana'
>>> pos = y.find(x) + 1
>>> y[:pos] + y[pos:].replace(x, 'other', 1)
'banaother'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import itertools
line = "hello, hi hello how are you hello"
x = "hello"
y = "something"
new_data = line.split(x)
new_data = ''.join(itertools.chain.from_iterable([(x, a) if i != 2 else (y, a) for i, a in enumerate(new_data)]))
```