# How to replace the second "is" from the sentence using replace method

Tags: python

```
strring ="My name is David and I live is India" # correct the grammer using find and replace method
new_str=strring.find("is")  # find the index of first "is"
print(new_str)
fnl_str=strring.replace("is","in")  # replace "is" with "in" ( My name is David and I live in India )
print(fnl_str)
```

Comment: Explain the complete issue or do `strring = strring.replace('live is','live in')`

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943504/right-to-left-string-replace-in-python

Comment: If you have something else in mind then look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/46705546/4320263

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [`str.rpartition()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rpartition.html) solves the case here, though not a general solution:

```
strring = "My name is David and I live is India"

first, sep, last = strring.rpartition('is')
print(first + 'in' + last)
# My name is David and I live in India
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `.split()` the string then use `enumerate` to create a list of  the indices of `items` containing the word `is`. Then you can take the second index in that list and use that `index` to change the item to `in`. Then use `' '.join()` to put it back together

```
s = "My name is David and I live is India"
s = s.split()
loc = []
for idx, item in enumerate(s):
    if item == 'is':
        loc.append(idx)

s[loc[1]] = 'in'

print(' '.join(s))
```

> ```
> My name is David and I live in India
> ```