# How to remove/replace strings before and after nth special character in a string?

Tags: python

How can I remove the third `_` and all strings before and also the 4th `_`  and all string after that using Python Replace method

```
st = "the_gis_osm_natural_a_free_1.shp"
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that with `str.replace`? There's like a dozen better solutions.

Comment: I am not sure about replace but I am sure I do not want to use the` [:]` method as the number of strings are dynamically changing so I thought many is better to eliminate strings based on the special characters which are always there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace nth occurrence of substring in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091557/replace-nth-occurrence-of-substring-in-string)

Comment: so what remains? `natural`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [split](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the string by `_` and then join the result:

```
start, end = 3, 4
filename = "the_gis_osm_natural_a_free_1.shp"
print('_'.join(filename.split("_")[start:end]))
```

**Output**

```
natural
```