# replace text in regex with index

Tags: python, regex, regexp-replace

I search with regex

regex has several results

I just want to replace it with my text in a specified index

```
pattern = '@name'
replace = '*rep*'
```

text

```
@name
@name
@name
```

The result I want `index=2`

```
@name
*rep*
@name
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091557/replace-nth-occurrence-of-substring-in-string

Answer (score -1):

Using `.findall` you will get the list, replace the element of a list using prefered index and use `.join` to get final expected results.

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = '@name'
>>> replace = '*rep*'
>>> text = '''@name
@name
@name'''
>>> re.findall(pattern,text)
['@name', '@name', '@name']
>>> index = 2
>>> re.findall(pattern,text)[index-1] = replace # use '-1' as index starts from zero
>>> text_list = re.findall(pattern,text)
>>> text_list[index-1] = replace
>>> ' '.join(text_list)
'@name *rep* @name'
```