# Python regex replace every 2nd occurrence in a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string with data that looks like this:

```
str1 = "[2.4],[5],[2.54],[4],[3.36],[4.46],[3.36],[4],[3.63],[4.86],[4],[4.63]"
```

I would want to replace every second iteration of `"],["` with `","` so it will look like this:

```
str2 = "[2.4,5],[2.54,4],[3.36,4.46],[3.36,4],[3.63,4.86],[4,4.63]"
```

Here is was I have so far:

```
str1 = "[2.4],[5],[2.54],[4],[3.36],[4.46],[3.36],[4],[3.63],[4.86],[4],[4.63]"
s2 = re.sub(r"],\[", ',', str1)
print(s2)
```

I was trying to mess around with this:

```
(.*?],\[){2}
```

But it does not seem to yield me the desired results.

I tried using loops but I only managed to replace only the second occurrence and nothing after using this sample code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35091558/14951530). And the code is:

```
import re

def replacenth(string, sub, wanted, n):
    where = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(sub, string)][n-1]
    before = string[:where]
    after = string[where:]
    after = after.replace(sub, wanted, 1)
    newString = before + after
    print(newString)
For these variables:

string = 'ababababababababab'
sub = 'ab'
wanted = 'CD'
n = 5
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
from itertools import count

str1 = "[2.4],[5],[2.54],[4],[3.36],[4.46],[3.36],[4],[3.63],[4.86],[4],[4.63]"
c = count(0)
print( re.sub(r"],\[", lambda x: "," if next(c) % 2 == 0 else x.group(), str1) )
# => [2.4,5],[2.54,4],[3.36,4.46],[3.36,4],[3.63,4.86],[4,4.63]
```

See [the Python demo](https://ideone.com/hkUxDV).

The regex is the same, `],\[`, it matches a literal `],[` text.

The `c = count(0)`  initializes the counter whose value is incremented upon each match inside a lambda expression used as the replacement argument. When the  counter is even, the match is replaced with a comma, else, it is kept as is.

Answer (score 3):

You could capture the parts you want to keep.

1. `(\[[^]]+)` - capture `[` and everything up to but not including the next `]`
2. `],\[` - match `],[`
3. `([^]]+)` - capture everything up to but not including next `]`

```
>>> re.sub(r"(\[[^]]+)],\[([^]]+)", r"\1,\2", str1)
'[2.4,5],[2.54,4],[3.36,4.46],[3.36,4],[3.63,4.86],[4,4.63]'
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to do it only using regex:

```
import re

text = '[2.4],[5],[2.54],[4],[3.36],[4.46],[3.36],[4],[3.63],[4.86],[4],[4.63]'

print(re.sub(r'],\[(.*?])', r',\1', text))
```

---

**Output:**

```
[2.4,5],[2.54,4],[3.36,4.46],[3.36,4],[3.63,4.86],[4,4.63]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler versions of Wiktor's solution, using `itertools.cycle` instead:

```
c = cycle((",", "],["))
print( re.sub(r"],\[", lambda x: next(c), str1) )
```

```
c = cycle((True, False))
print( re.sub(r"],\[", lambda x: "," if next(c) else x.group(), str1) )
```